# How to update values from multiple row table to another multiple table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables with multiple records in and I want to update one table's rows with a value from another tables records matched on `ORD_NAME` and `OP_NAME`.

My SQL so far:

```
INSERT INTO OPS_NOTREQUIRED (ORD_NAME, OP_NAME, STATUS)
VALUES ('1', '10', 'DELETE')
INSERT INTO OPS_NOTREQUIRED (ORD_NAME, OP_NAME, STATUS)
VALUES ('2', '10', 'DELETE')
INSERT INTO OPS_NOTREQUIRED (ORD_NAME, OP_NAME, STATUS)
VALUES ('3', '10', '')

INSERT INTO IMPORT (ORD_NAME, ORD_QTY, ORD_PART, ORD_PARTREV, ORD_DUEDATE, OP_NAME, EAI_Status)
VALUES ('1', '400', '1234', '1', '2023-12-01 09:10:04.530', '10', 'NULL')
INSERT INTO IMPORT (ORD_NAME, ORD_QTY, ORD_PART, ORD_PARTREV, ORD_DUEDATE, OP_NAME, EAI_Status)
VALUES ('2', '400', '1234', '1', '2023-12-01 09:10:04.530', '10', 'NULL')
INSERT INTO IMPORT (ORD_NAME, ORD_QTY, ORD_PART, ORD_PARTREV, ORD_DUEDATE, OP_NAME, EAI_Status)
VALUES ('3', '400', '1234', '1', '2023-12-01 09:10:04.530', '10', 'NULL')



UPDATE [IMPORT] 
SET EAI_Status = 'DELETE' 
WHERE (SELECT EAI_Status FROM OPS_NOTREQUIRED) = 'DELETE'
```

I want the `IMPORT` table to have the same values as the `OPS_NOTREQUIRED` table for column `STATUS`, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the merge command.

```
MERGE INTO IMPORT
USING OPS_NOTREQUIRED
ON IMPORT.ORD_NAME = OPS_NOTREQUIRED.ORD_NAME
AND IMPORT.OP_NAME = OPS_NOTREQUIRED.OP_NAME
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET EAI_Status = OPS_NOTREQUIRED.STATUS;
```

Comment: Merge should be avoided, it has [lots of issues](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=50&safe=off&source=hp&ei=dpzXWsioI8qisgHLyamYBA&btnG=Search&q=sql+merge+problems) many still unresolved.

Comment: Agree. The complexities of MERGE is overkill for this simple update.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a regular inner join in an update statement:

```
UPDATE I
SET EAI_Status = O.STATUS
FROM OPS_NOTREQUIRED O
JOIN IMPORT I
    ON I.ORD_NAME = O.ORD_NAME
    AND I.OP_NAME = O.OP_NAME
```

Note the use of aliases that allow the `UPDATE` clause to conveniently reference the target table already referenced in the `FROM` clause.